# Jquery: select react to .click() but not to .change()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am working with the wordpress plugin Calculated Fields Form, which uses an ajax calendar with date fields and updates the date when the user click on a given day.
I want, however, to change the date even when the user changes the month or the year. 
I am trying to detect when the field for choosing the month/year (a select field) is being changed. However, I get no response to the .change() handler.

```
$(document).on("change", "#ui-datepicker-div select", function (event) {
    console.log("change handler: new month is ", $(this).val());
});
```

This is never being called, even after I change the value. 
Notice that: the selector is correct, as the code above works if I substitute "change" with "click". This should also cover the possibilities that the element is not yet ready, jquery not loaded properly, etc.
I am able to do anything with that element, but to change() it does not respond.
Any idea on why that may be the case? Or a turn-around way to insert some code in the moment the select field has changed?

Answer (score 0):

The only possible reason could be because, there is no change event happening on the element.

Maybe your calender is not using the html select element, instead something like Jquery select2.

If so the change handler will be different based on the ui library you are using !!

please post the html code !!

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the source code, I am assuming that WordPress's Calculated Fields Form is using jQuery's datepicker. In that case, to trigger the datepicker's select field, you need to use the "onSelect" option. Try and see if it helps.

```
$("datepicker_input_field").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
        var date = $(this).val();
        var text = dateText;
        console.log(date, text);
        alert('Event is triggered on change');
    }
});​
```

Comment: Yes, that's the datepicker indeed! Seemed a good idea, but I still am not getting response, unfortunately...